# google storage python JSON client eternal 502 when uploading media to bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-client

This is my first time using Google Storage json api, and I am trying to do a simple image file *UPLOAD* to a bucket using the python client library.  It seems that I am correctly getting credentials (application default) because I can *LIST* the contents of the bucket when I provide the credentials to the discovery.build() method, and then the same listing call fails when I do not provide credentials.  In terms of the ACL, I am maybe not 100% solid on how to set the access controls in general, **BUT** I am pretty confident that that is not the issue, because I have also tried to execute my script on a Compute Engine VM after configuring it with Cloud Storage API READ and WRITE access in the console.

Further, I am aware of the documentation's advice to retry promptly (with 'exponential back off') when you get a 502 Bad Gateway response, but I am getting this error every single time I have tried for a couple hours now.  So, either the Google Storage service is broken in certain ways, or my client is broken, right? Even further, I am able to push up the jpeg file on the command line using `gsutil cp ...`, which makes me think I am broken and not Google, and that the bucket is writable with my default credentials. Sound good?

Here's my very simple client script, which is a jury-rigged from [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-python-samples) official sample:

```
import json
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
image = MediaFileUpload('up.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
req = service.objects().insert_media(bucket='somebucket', media_body=image)
resp = req.execute()
print(json.dumps(resp, indent=2))
```

And here is the trace I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload.py", line 10, in <module>
    resp = req.execute()
  File "/Envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 729, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 502 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/somebucket/o?uploadType=media&alt=media returned "Bad Gateway">
```

I have tried python 2.7 and python 3.5, so I don't think that is the issue (docs told me google python client is functional in 3.5, but not as well tested).  Also, I have tried a 'resumable upload' variation on this, as per [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload), and I get the same, ever-faithful 502 Bad Gateway. Is google broken? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a destination name for your object. I believe that you want the method `service.objects().insert()` instead of `service.objects().insert_media()`. So the full line would be:

```
req = client.objects().insert(
    bucket='somebucket',
    name='nameOfObject',
    media_body=image)
```

There's [a complete example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#examples) on the objects.insert documentation page.

I'm not sure why you're getting a 502, though. That may be a bug.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much.